# Matlmul for N square matices

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and was wondering if something like numpy.matmul exists for N square matrices? Can this not be done without a loop?

I don't know how to do this without looping through the matrices.

Comment: Are all the N matrices the same size? If so, `np.mamul` works on stacks of matrices.

Comment: Your phrasing is ambiguous.  Do you mean you have N matrices, or do you mean you have matrices that are size NxN?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to multiply N matrices, yes you can use `np.linalg.multi_dot` like this:

```
np.linalg.multi_dot([A, B, C])
```

which is equivalent to `A @ B @ C` or `np.matmul(np.matmul(A, B), C)` or `np.dot(np.dot(A, B), C)` or `A.dot(B).dot(C)`.

And if you want to multiply many matrices, you can use `reduce` from the `functools` module.

```
matrices = [A, B, C, D, E, F]
result = reduce(np.dot, matrices)
```